# Room - LiveData not triggered

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata

I'm trying to work with Room database & LiveData.
I have ViewModels which holds LiveData they got from dao.
If I update a `Transaction`, then `LiveData<List<Transaction>>` is observed ok, but `LiveData<Transaction>` is not observed at all. How is that possible? What am i doing wrong?

```
public abstract class Dao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM transact WHERE deleted = :value")
    public abstract LiveData<List<Transaction>> allTransactions(boolean value);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM transact WHERE guid = :guid AND deleted = :value ")
    public abstract LiveData<Transaction> getTransaction(String guid, boolean value);

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    protected abstract void updateTransaction(Transaction transaction);
}
```

There is similar issue, which mentions Dagger complications when non `@Singleton` annotated class was used, that's unfortunately not my problem, even if i use Dagger.

Comment: "How is that possible?" -- perhaps Room is not looking for individual entity changes as part of its invalidation tracking.

Comment: Well, I'll request for renaming to DeadData then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was inside `AppCompatActivity` which holds `ViewModel` with `LiveData`.

LiveData observer has been called only for Fragment, not for Activity.
I used `AppCompatActivity` with `LifecycleOwner` interface implemented, but correct is to implement `LifecycleRegistryOwner`.

Credits: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63764057

Comment: Can you share the codes that create the viewmodel, and add observer?

Answer (score 0):

In the new version 1.0.0 Alpha 9-1 , Android Developer released notes announced

> This is a major release where core lifecycle artifacts (runtime,
>   common) and arch core (common) reach to stable version 1.0.0.
>
> Along with this change, Support Library 26.1.0 now depends on these
>   libraries. Both AppCompatActivity and Support Fragment now implement
>   the LifecycleOwner interface.
>
> This release also depends on Support Library 26.1.0 to take advantage
>   of the new integration.

Both AppCompatActivity and Support Fragment should be implemented the LifecycleOwner interface now