# Observer onChanged not working while calling Room.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().execSQL(queryUpdate)

Tags: android-room, android-livedata, observers

Kindly understand my question first

I am using this code to update C_P table in db, who have a trigger on it, which is going to insert any new value in my queuelist table.
My database instance is singleton.

1. when I insert by using this

   ```
   "queueListDatabase.dbAccess().insertTask(queueList)"
   ```

observer on changed call
so my observer is working fine.

2. I have implemented a trigger in room like this

   ```
   " db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER if not exists CONTROL_PARAM_TRIGGER" +
                                        " AFTER UPDATE " +
                                        "ON C_P" +
                                        " BEGIN " +
                                        " INSERT INTO QueueList(title, description) 
   values('CONTROL_PARAM', new.order_sku_limit||' '||new.cmnum||' '||new.avnum); " +
                                        " END;");"
   ```

Trigger is also working fine, like when ever I have called

```
  String queryUpdate="Update CONTROL_PARAM Set abc= 'xyz'";
  queueListDatabase.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().execSQL(queryUpdate)
```

it  update in C_P and also inserting in QueueList;
but it wont fire the onchange method of observer.
if I check value after execSQL query, Value is inserted in QueueList table.

P.S : Kindly understand this I can not use dao @RawQuery(writing raw query in db interface) because queries are coming from server.(Kindly suggest me alternate solution if anyone have it)

Here my code for observer

```
  roomObserver = new Observer<List<QueueList>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<QueueList> periods) {
            if (periods != null && periods.size()>0) {
                Log.e("dbValue", periods.size() + "");
            }
        }

    };

    queueListDatabase.dbAccess().fetchAllTasks().observe(this,roomObserver);
```

Kindly suggest my any link or solution
I have already check multiple solution (Link are mentioned below), but they does not meet the requirement.

[Android ROOM - LiveData not triggered when using custom insert query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704969/android-room-livedata-not-triggered-when-using-custom-insert-query)

[Room - LiveData observer does not trigger when database is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742445/room-livedata-observer-does-not-trigger-when-database-is-updated)

[Insert on Room DB does not trigger Observer on Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589304/insert-on-room-db-does-not-trigger-observer-on-activity)

[Observer not triggered on room database change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852692/observer-not-triggered-on-room-database-change)

[Room : LiveData from Dao will trigger Observer.onChanged on every Update, even if the LiveData value has no change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215666/room-livedata-from-dao-will-trigger-observer-onchanged-on-every-update-even-i?rq=1)

[Room - LiveData not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45130873/room-livedata-not-triggered?rq=1)

[Android Room : LiveData callback of update insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462128/android-room-livedata-callback-of-update-insert?rq=1)

[Android ROOM - LiveData not triggered when using custom insert query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704969/android-room-livedata-not-triggered-when-using-custom-insert-query)

[Notify observers when executing a custom sql query ROOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579165/notify-observers-when-executing-a-custom-sql-query-room)

[Room - LiveData observer does not trigger when database is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742445/room-livedata-observer-does-not-trigger-when-database-is-updated)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery

Comment: If anyone found same problem,
I have found a solution
use this line 
 instance.getInvalidationTracker().refreshVersionsAsync();
after executing "excSQL" line
queueListDatabase.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().execSQL(queryUpdate)